# How to have indirectly self nested components in Vue JS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I manage to create directly self nested components using the `name` property and all works perfectly.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Hi, I'm component A!</span>
        <component-a></component-a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'component-a',
        components: {
            'component-a': this
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I want to create indirectly self nested components. Something like this:

ComponentA.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Hi, I'm component A!</span>
        <component-b v-if="hasItems" v-for="item in items" :item="item"></component-b>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ComponentB from './ComponentB.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'component-a',
        components: {
            'component-b': ComponentB
        },
        props: ['items'],
        computed: {
            hasItems() {
                return this.items.length > 0
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ComponentB.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Hi, I'm component B!</span>
        <component-a v-if="hasItems" :items="item.items"></component-a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

    export default {
        name: 'component-b',
        components: {
            'component-a': ComponentA
        },
        props: ['item'],
        computed: {
            hasItems() {
                return this.item.items.length > 0
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But that fails. I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined. (found in component )

Has anyone came across something like this and was able to solve it? According to the documentation we have control recursive components with conditional rendering that what I am doing... I even tried to use the `name` prop on the components but it did nothing (nor I think it should since the components are not directly self-nested).

Answer (score 5):

I tried your code and I also ended up with the same error, without a clue on how to proceed. Later I closed my `vue-cli` and tried directly using vue.js from a CDN (standalone version), and it worked alright.

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/z09Luphg/

There is no magic going on here. `Component A` and `Component B` call each other with a `counterValue`. Once the `counterValue` reaches some limit, the recursion stops.

If you do not get a better answer, and if you are unable to modify your app architecture, you can try using this **standalone** vue.js method.

**EDIT: more info below**

On further research today, I came across this github discussion on webpack cyclical imports / circular dependencies: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1788

The **standalone** jsFiddle example above does not require any ES6 imports. In my sample code, Vue.js registers components globally before initiating the app. Therefore it works without any issues.

In summary, this does not look like an issue with Vue.js, but a webpack / es6 limitation based on current info. I may be wrong, please keep exploring further!

Comment: I've been analizing the link that you have provided and it seems that the problem is indeed related to webpack and how circular imports are handled.  But I wasn't able to find a solution or a work-around... I have updated laravel-elixir-webpack-official to the latest version and tried some things that are referenced in the link, but the truth is that my webpack knowledge isn't very deep and I ran out of options. I'll keep trying to understand what is happening and I'll post here when I come to something. If in the mean time you find anything that can help, please share. Thank you.

Comment: Actually in such cases, my first choice is not to mess with webpack config too much. Reason is because it becomes a nightmare to maintain and explain to other team members. That is why I did not want to read deep into that github issues page on how others managed to get around it. It should be easier to change the app design instead to avoid cyclic imports. But if I do find a simple method, I will get back and edit my answer above.

Comment: I shouldn't have to change my APP design due to webpack limitions. It makes sense in the APP context to have the component structure like that.  I really hope that there is a workaround to this...

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Lets wait for more responses to your question. Pls keep it in open state, so that it is noticed by others. Even I would like to have an answer for this, as it is a matter of time before I run into a situation like yours.

Comment: I am facing the exact problem. Any further info would be appreciated. @AntónioQuadrado did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

There is actually some good [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) and some different solutions for this issue, such as using asynchronous Webpack imports or registering self needed components globally.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Hi, I'm component A!</span>
        <component-a></component-a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      name: 'component-b',
      components: {
         // async import: 
         ComponentA: () => import('./ComponentA.vue')
      }
  }
</script>
```